# Как выбрать данные о дате и времени из базы данных в нужном мне формате?

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x

Проблема состоит в том, что у меня есть поле, в которое я передаю дату и время (`DATETIME`). Изначально передавал с помощью
`` INSERT INTO `table`(..., `date_time`, ...) VALUES (..., now(), ...) ``.

Итак, выдираю я данные и хочу отделить дату от времени. Посоветуйте кто что сможет, желательно для Python 3.

Желаемый результат: Сейчас: 23:45 минут. Текущая дата: 09.09.2015

На данный момент тестирую все с помощью `print()`, возможно бага в этом.

Время в секундах тоже подходит. Использую библиотеку pymysql

Answer (score 2):

Ответ оказался проще, чем я думал. В конце запроса с вывода нужно было дописать .time() или date()